# Unity installed version higher than game project version - can't open the game project anymore

Tags: unity

Long story short - I had to uninstall Unity and Unity Hub and reinstall them again.
I ended up installing Unity version **2020.2.1f1**.
Some of my game projects were made using version **2020.1.6f1**
Now I cannot open them - there is a yellow warning triangle next to those games in Unity Hub.

I am installing version **2020.1.17f1** as I type these.

So my questions:

1. Is there no backwards compatibility between newer versions of Unity and older games?
2. How do people deal with this?
   I've heard people transition their games during development into newer versions of Unity but I wasn't even able to open the games made with older version.
3. How would I go around this if I had spent 2 years or more of development time and was suddenly locked out from my game project - how do I prevent situations like these?

Here are my Unity versions installed:
[image]

And here are my games (tutorials mostly):

[image]

I may have answered my own question, but still need your input guys. I just noticed that there is a 'Select Version' dropdown on the right that allows me to open a game project in Unity version I have installed on my system. Is this how you deal with those issues?

[image]

Comment: Are you really locked out or is it more of a warning that the used version does not exist and you need to pick a version (as it is written at the right "Select a version"). Usually picking a higher version and opening the project will tell you to make a backup and it will try to convert it to the newer version, in most cases it fully works but if not, you were told to do a backup before. A minor version upgrade is doing less problems compared to a major one.

Comment: It's a warning. I may have overreacted a little.